# Block Truncation Coding MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, block

I am trying to implement block truncation coding (BTC) on an image in matlab. In order to do BTW you have to calculate the mean and standard deviation of each 4x4 block of pixels. However, I need to store the mean as a variable number of bits as in the number of bits that the mean will be stored in is passed into the function that calculates the mean. I'm not sure how to do this part, can anyone help?

Comment: It seems that your question is not actually related to BTC, but only to writing the output into a bit-stream. Maybe you could re-write it to remove the BTC part, change the title and rather focus on how exactly you want to store the output. E.g. does the number of bits vary from block to block or only from image to image? Do you just want to measure the resulting PSNR or other quality metric or actually write to a file? With what encoding? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy and clean approach to variable bit lengths-encoding would require the use of the [fixed-point toolbox](http://www.mathworks.ch/products/fixed-point-designer/). E.g. as follows

```
function o = encode1(val, numBits)
o = fi(val, 0, numBits, 0)
```

If you are rather bound to pure Matlab you could just [`and`](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/fixedpoint/ref/bitand.html) them away and 'simulate' the precision loss if you only want to benchmark your encoding.

```
function o = encode2(val, numBits)
o = bitand(uint8(val), 256 - 2^(8-numBits));
```

On the other hand, if you're planning to actually encode into a file and not just simulate the encoding, you would need to establish a bit-stream which is not byte-aligned. This can be a bit tiring to do. Trading off efficiency for ease of implementation, you could use [`dec2bin`](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html) to work with a string of `'0'` and `'1'` characters. Again, toolboxes can be of help here, e.g. the [communication systems toolbox](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/comm/index.html) provides the [`de2bi`](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/comm/ref/de2bi.html) function.